# DateInterval doesnt add a date and no errors?

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I'm trying to split a holiday in two, given a date in the middle.

```
$splitdate = new DateTime($_POST['date']);

// Split date = 2020-08-04
$holiday1end = $holiday2start = $splitdate;

$holiday1end->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$holiday2start->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));

echobr("Holiday 1: ".$holiday1end->format("Y-m-d"));
echobr("Then " . $splitdate->format("Y-m-d"));
echobr("Holiday 1: " . $holiday2start->format("Y-m-d");
```

This is the output I get:

```
Holiday 1: 2020-08-04
Then 2020-08-04
Holiday 1: 2020-08-04
```

It doesnt make sense, originally I had the DateInterval as 'P1D' but that didnt work so I tried removing two days, I'm still not getting any changes, or errors either.  What am I doing wrong here?

Edit for Clarity: $holiday1end should be one day less than $splitdate,
$holiday2start should be one day more than $splitdate, but neither of them are changing.

Comment: What / Where is `$begin`???

Comment: Sorry, $begin is another part of the code, but thats not the issue here, the issue is the $holiday1end and $holiday2start

Comment: I am just saying that for debugging your part of code, please provide `$begin` as its being used in your part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you do like this,

```php
$splitdate = new DateTime('2010-12-31');
$holiday1end = $holiday2start = $splitdate;
```

The instance of object in `$splitdate` is passed as reference to other variables. And as you are `sub`tracting and `add`ing same number of days, so it seems that the code is not working. However its working properly but due to shared / referenced instance of same object, all effect goes to same object.

However if you do something like bellow, You'll notice that 1 day is added to date (basically 2 days are subtracted and then 3 days are added).

```php
$date = '2010-12-31';

$splitdate = new DateTime($date);
$holiday1end = $holiday2start = $splitdate;

$holiday1end->sub(new DateInterval('P2D'));
$holiday2start->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));

echo "Holiday 1: ".$holiday1end->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Then " . $splitdate->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Holiday 2: " . $holiday2start->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
```

If you separate the `DateTime` object instances, you'll get your desired results.

```php
$date = '2010-12-31';

$splitdate = new DateTime($date);
$holiday1end = new DateTime($date);
$holiday2start = new DateTime($date);

$holiday1end->sub(new DateInterval('P2D'));
$holiday2start->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));

echo "Holiday 1: ".$holiday1end->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Then " . $splitdate->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Holiday 1: " . $holiday2start->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
```

[Working Example of above code](https://www.tehplayground.com/xOodsd2pf9Ii0Cp2)

[Example with 1 Day difference](https://www.tehplayground.com/ddTNq5czcwwz4Fu3)

Comment: Thats so weird, I wonder why its being passed as reference?  Anyway thank you for your help, I wasnt getting anywhere with this!

Comment: @Chud37 That's how [objects work](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) in PHP and many other languages. It isn't specific to `DateTime` or PHP.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Please see my other answer. And if there is any bug /  error / mistake or if it lacked some aspect, kindly advise or update.

Comment: @UmairKhan Not sure what you mean. Chud37 said "I wonder why its being passed as reference" and I explained why.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding as new answer instead of rewording / rephrasing old one.**

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299341/dateinterval-doesnt-add-a-date-and-no-errors/63300362#comment111937833_63300362) by @Álvaro González on my other answer that objects in many languages behave some what different than what we think when passing objects between different variables.

Quoting from [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

> One of the key-points of PHP 5 OOP that is often mentioned is that
> "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely
> true. This section rectifies that general thought using some examples.
>
> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to
> write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't
> contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object
> identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.
> When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another
> variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of
> the identifier, which points to the same object.

**Explaination:** (what I can understand from this)

If `$var1` contains an object and you try to initialize `$var2` with `$var1` using [assignment operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) (`=`) like `$var2 = $var1` the contents of `$var1` are copied (passed by **value**) to `$var2` but as per manual, in case of `$var1`, `$var1` **does not contain the object itself as value** but a mere **object identifier which**, in simple words, **points to actual object**. So in case of above initialization, the **object identifier** in `$var1` is copied (passed by **value**) to `$var2` and as now both variables `$var1`, `$var2` contain value that points to same object, so it seems that the assignment acted as passed by **reference** instead of passed by **value**.

So when you do like this,

```php
$splitdate = new DateTime('2010-12-31');
$holiday1end = $holiday2start = $splitdate;
```

You are actually coping **object identifier** of same object to other variables. And as you are `sub`tracting and `add`ing same number of days, so all these operations are applied to same object. And it seems that the code is not working, however its working properly.

If you do something like bellow, You'll notice that 1 day is added to date (basically 2 days are subtracted and then 3 days are added).

```php
$date = '2010-12-31';

$splitdate = new DateTime($date);
$holiday1end = $holiday2start = $splitdate;

$holiday1end->sub(new DateInterval('P2D'));
$holiday2start->add(new DateInterval('P3D'));

echo "Holiday 1: ".$holiday1end->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Then " . $splitdate->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Holiday 2: " . $holiday2start->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
```

If you separate the `DateTime` object instances, you'll get your desired results.

```php
$date = '2010-12-31';

$splitdate = new DateTime($date);
$holiday1end = new DateTime($date);
$holiday2start = new DateTime($date);

$holiday1end->sub(new DateInterval('P2D'));
$holiday2start->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));

echo "Holiday 1: ".$holiday1end->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Then " . $splitdate->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Holiday 1: " . $holiday2start->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
```

[Working Example of above code](https://www.tehplayground.com/xOodsd2pf9Ii0Cp2)

[Example with 1 Day difference](https://www.tehplayground.com/ddTNq5czcwwz4Fu3)

If you want to copy the object itself, you can use [clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) which makes a **shallow copy of the object**. So using example code in your question with `clone`.

```
$date = '2010-12-31';

$splitdate = new DateTime($date);

// $holiday1end = clone $splitdate;
// $holiday2start = clone $splitdate;

// OR
// $holiday1end = clone $splitdate;
// $holiday2start = clone $holiday1end;

// OR in one line
$holiday2start = clone $holiday1end = clone $splitdate;

$holiday1end->sub(new DateInterval('P2D'));
$holiday2start->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));

echo "Holiday 1: ".$holiday1end->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Then " . $splitdate->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
echo "Holiday 2: " . $holiday2start->format("Y-m-d")."\n";
```

You get your desired results([Example](https://www.tehplayground.com/QDxecizEdMImHl63)).